# VBA GET request returning 404 when curl returns 200

Tags: vba, excel, curl

I'm using Excel (because the data is saved in a spreadsheet) to go through a list of a few thousand links and see if they are broken, AKA do they return a 404 or not when I RESTful GET them.  However, my VBA code is returning something other than when I use curl, and in this case curl is right (the page exists).  Here's my code with the link that's causing trouble (it's inside a subroutine, don't worry):

```
For i = StartRow To EndRow
    Let copyRange = "H" & i
    Let writeRange = "T" & i
    query = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(copyRange).Value
    If query = "" Then

    Else
        With zipService
            .Open "GET", query, False
        End With
        zipService.send
        zipResult = zipService.Status
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(writeRange).Value = zipResult
    End If

Next i
```

The curl command line:

```
curl –sL –w “%{http_code} \n” http://URLHERE” –o /dev/null
```

The link that's causing trouble: http://www.stopwaste.org/home/index.asp#

Curl returns 200, VBA returns 404. The same link has failed several times, so I don't think it's a "server was just down for a second" situation.  I thought it my have been a problem with the # character, so I removed it but got the exact same response.  The code is successfully reporting other 404's, so somehow there's a situation that creates false positives (or negatives, whichever you want to call it).  the "If query = "" Then" is so that there aren't GETs to empty URLS, VBA doesn't like those.

I'm pretty stumped here, and was hoping someone would be able to help me out.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use `.FollowHyperlink` to check if the URL exists?

See this example.

```
Sub Sample()
  Dim url As String

  url = "http://www.stopwaste.org/home/index.asp#"
  Debug.Print url, CheckIfURLExists(url)

  url = "http://www.Google.com"
  Debug.Print url, CheckIfURLExists(url)

  url = "http://www.Goo00000gle.com"
  Debug.Print url, CheckIfURLExists(url)
End Sub

Function CheckIfURLExists(ByVal sLink As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (sLink)
    CheckIfURLExists = Err.Number = 0
End Function
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: I'm going with a combination of all these answers (double, triple check), but yours was the most helpful because it gave me an alternate method.

Answer (score 1):

**Removed the '#' character and it worked just fine.**

[image]

**In Fiddler I saw that browser didn't send '#' character at all:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line to include double quotes:

```
 zipService.send ""
```

---

Also, try reseting zipService after each URL

```
Set zipService = Nothing
```

---

I'm assuming the excel version works for some of your URLs since your pointing out one specific one.?.?